# Is there a package or font which has a letter like Ł but with a double crossing?

Tags: fonts, packages

Like above, I want to know if there is a package or font which would allow me to type a letter `\L` but with two crossings instead of one i. e. a double crossed L (L with two strokes). It would be a great letter to use for me in the paper I'm writing.

Comment: Not a package but you could manually input [Ⱡ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%B1%A0) - or make your own macro defining something like `\LL`.

Comment: @Miztli If I try to manually input it, it gives me an error because of unicode character. Anyway, I thought of something more like Ł, with the stroke being at an angle.

Comment: You'll have to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to you preamble or compile using XeTeX or LuaTeX. As for L with a double stroke at an angle, I'm not aware of such a character so you'd probably have to come up with a personalised way of composing/printing such a character if Ⱡ will not do.

Comment: Related: (same method should work here) [inserting a single unicode character with pdflatex](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/311057)

Comment: @Miztli `inputenc` won't help if the font you're using doesn't have the relevant glyph. (Also, it's not needed in current distributions.) Since I suspect this isn't common, then using an OpenType font that has it and XeTeX or LuaTeX would be the way to do this.

Comment: Ah, yes! Of course, you're quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a math symbol,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\LL}{\text{\normalfont\fontencoding{OT1}\itshape\makeLL}}
\newcommand{\makeLL}{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$L$}%
  \makebox[\dimen0][r]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\hspace{0.15ex}\symbol{32}}}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace{0.1ex}\symbol{32}}}%
    $L$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$|\LL|$

$|L|$

\end{document}
```

[image]